# Is it possible to merge changes from one source to multiple destinations in Perforce?

Tags: perforce, branching-and-merging, perforce-integrate

We have a case where changes were made to a file in a source branch that need to get propagated to multiple destinations?

Here is an illustration:

[image]

I know I could do each one individually, but it seems like with the right wildcards in the filespec this might work.

We tried this viewspec:

> //dev/main/file.txt //dev/r*/file.txt

But we got this error:

> Integration errors: Incompatible wildcards '//dev/main/file.txt' <-> '//dev/r*/file.txt'

Is this possible?

Comment: No way to one shot that with a wildcard I'm afraid. You'll have to script that one. **p4 dirs** will be handy for you to get the directories on the right hand side.

Comment: Either you have to do it one by one or you could create a branch spec that lists all the single mappings. The latter comes in handy if you intend to update the target branches later on (with new changes from the source branch).

Comment: I didn't realize that one branch spec could list all of these at once, I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comment from @Matt:

No way to one shot that with a wildcard I'm afraid. You'll have to script that one. p4 dirs will be handy for you to get the directories on the right hand side

Answer (score 2):

You have to perform multiple integrate/resolve commands, one set for each target branch.

But, you can include all the integrations in a single changelist, and submit them all with a single submit, if you wish, so that they are all submitted at once with a single change description.